# Can I load a camera inside ImageView?

Tags: android

I want to load a camera inside Imageview, is it possible? I am new to android.
I want to get x and y coordinates of the screen after loading a camera. I have implemented camera activity but it opens systems camera. If I manage to load camera inside Imageview, I can get those coordinates.

Comment: Try Using Camera 2 Api Check their Documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add camera preview into `SurfaceView` not into an `ImageView`. Then you can create fully customisable preview screen.

```
class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }
...
}
```

There is a detailed documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)